# Divisibility of sums of combinations of integers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I have given a list of $N$ numbers. I want to choose any $M$ of them. I can choose it in ${N \choose M}$ ways. Now I want to determine how many of these chosen groups have a sum, which is divisible by $D$.

Comment: That depends on the list of numbers.

Comment: I've edited the title. The term "divisible group" is most commonly used to refer to something entirely different.

Comment: @anon: What if the 'N' is the list of first 'N' natural numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, count how many of the $N$ are in each congruence class $\pmod D$ and call them $d_0,d_1,d_2, \ldots, d_{D-1}$.  Then find the partitions of $D$.  For a partition like $9=4+2+2+1$ you have $d_4\cdot d_1 \cdot \frac {d_2(d_2-1)}{2!}$ groups.  Can you generalize?